# Formula For A Recursive Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, recursion

So I have learned to program using recursion, but I have not learned how to actually do this in math. If I have the sequence {4,8,12}, and the question asks for a recursive formula to solve for an+1, would it be as simple as: an+1  = an + 4 ? This seems correct to me, but it also seems too simple.

Comment: Seems right, but you need to be sure that that is your sequence.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you know only some first terms of a sequence and no other information is given, then trying to continue the sequence is not math. There is no reason for the sequence not to continue as $4,8,12,0,0,0,0$, or $4,8,12,37,37,1,4,0,0,0,...$.

Comment: The formula could've been given by $a_{n+1}=0.5a_n+2+2n$, which also satisfies those first 3 terms.

Answer (score 1):

If the explicit formula for a sequence is $a_n=a_1+n(d-1)$, then the recursive formula is $a_n=a_{n-1}+d$. Here, we have that the explicit formula is $a_n=4+4(n-1)$, then the recursive formula will be $a_n=a_{n-1}+4$. You are correct.